# How can I decode base64 encoded strings that does not end with equality sign in Swift?

Tags: swift, base64

I have a base64 encoded payload from JWT from the server side that is the string: `eyJleHAiOjE1MTU0Mjk2NjYsInN1YiI6MX0`. But this string does not end with an equality sign. And when I try to decode it with Swift it does not work unless I put an equality sign at the end.

So this does not work:

```
let base64encoded = "eyJleHAiOjE1MTU0Mjk2NjYsInN1YiI6MX0"

let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64encoded)!
print(decodedData)
let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8)
print(decodedString)
```

But this works:

```
let base64encoded = "eyJleHAiOjE1MTU0Mjk2NjYsInN1YiI6MX0="

let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64encoded)!
print(decodedData)
let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8)
print(decodedString)
```

What can I do to make this work for all base64encoded strings? I expect that I can't just add an equality sign after all base64encoded strings. Should I check if the string ends with equality sign first and then add it if does not? Is there a good solution to this?

This is a portion of the Golang code on the server side from a third party JWT package:

```
// Encode JWT specific base64url encoding with padding stripped
func EncodeSegment(seg []byte) string {
    return strings.TrimRight(base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(seg), "=")
}

// Decode JWT specific base64url encoding with padding stripped
func DecodeSegment(seg string) ([]byte, error) {
    if l := len(seg) % 4; l > 0 {
        seg += strings.Repeat("=", 4-l)
    }

    return base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(seg)
}
```

Comment: Well, the `=` seems required. How are you getting the value of the variable `base64encoded`? I would look into why the `=` is being trimmed off in the first place

Comment: Updated the post with server side code. The equality sign is being trimmed for some reason.

Comment: The [`TrimRight`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRight) is explicitly removing it. `=` isn't a valid character within a `URL`. I don't know why they don't just percent sign encode it, as `%3D`, though